# Memory leaks sensitive information - Ionic

Tags: security, debugging, ionic-framework, memory, ionic2

In our application, during the security testing, they were able to get the request and response details from the memory dump.
Please find the following details they were able to get from the dump, is there any option or process we can implement to remove this from happening:

```
CordovaHttpPlugin
post https:/XXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX/login
username: XXXXXXXX
password XXXXXXX
json
Authorization
Bearer
null
Content-Type
application/json
Accept
text
ionic
```

Security team is using tool "**fridump**" for getting the memory data.

Is there any possible methods in ionic or tools that we can add to avoid this type of memory dump.

Comment: using a js framework alwayswill leak security, in order to protect user data from being network watched, u can use encryption plugin to secure ur app like : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/aes-256, so in this way network data will be 100% protected but still if app apk was opened as rar or android , the built prod js files will contain the secure password that will allow atacker to know how to decrypt ur requests, so in order to save the passwords, u can use enterprise secret vault, or go with chunking the password into different pages and then re concating the chunked files upon usage.

Comment: Thanks, @MostafaHarb, we are trying to minimize the memory data.
On Checking with the security team, they mentioned as long as the device is preventing the application from installing in a rooted device then it would be ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were not able to resolve the issue. The security team advised us to prevent the application from installing in a rooted device for now, and also have all the data saved in the mobile side encrypted.